# Is it possible to add a cipher for an sftp client?

Tags: ssh, aes, sftp

I'm running into an issue where a server was upgraded to RHEL 6.5, and we have automated scripts on an RHEL 5.9 install that connects through sftp and ssh commands.

Now, the new server only supports the ciphers aes128-ctr, aes192-ctr, and aes256-ctr.

I was able to update the ssh commands to use the -c option with aes256-ctr and this worked:

```
ssh -c aes256-ctr ${remote_host} ${my_command}
```

However, when I tried do the equivalent for sftp:

```sh
sftp -oCipher=aes256-ctr ${remote_host} <<< $'get /home/me/* me/'
```

I am getting an error that the client does not support the same ciphers as the server:

> no matching cipher found: client
>   arcfour256,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
>   server aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr

These ssh and sftp command are executed on the same RHEL 5.9 box, so I'm wondering why this works for ssh and not sftp?

Also, how do fix this so I can connect using sftp without any client side changes?

Comment: you can compile openssh from source on the rhel 5.x machine, that would solve your problems.

Comment: you need to use `ciphers` instead of `cipher`. `cipher` is for ssh protocol version 1 which you should never use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix a cipher mismatch issue with sftp?](http://superuser.com/questions/918118/how-do-i-fix-a-cipher-mismatch-issue-with-sftp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sftp -o` accepts `ssh_option` ([source](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sftp)).

`ssh_config` [says](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) that `Cipher` is for ssh protocol v1 (which you should never use) and `Ciphers` is for ssh protocol v2.

Answer (score 1):

The `Cipher` directive is for SSH version 1 (which is not in use nowadays).

For SSH version 2, use the `Ciphers`:

```
sftp -oCiphers=aes256-ctr
```

See [`ssh_config` man page](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config).

---

Though note that the `sftp` supports the `-c` switch too. So there's no need for using the `-o`.

See the [`sftp` man page](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp):

> `-c cipher`
>
> Selects the cipher to use for encrypting the data transfers.
>   This option is directly passed to [ssh(1)](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh).

The option is supported since [OpenSSH 5.4](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-5.4). The change is disguised as *"Support most of scp(1)'s commandline arguments in sftp(1)*".

---

Note the command-line argument `-c` is primarily an equivalent to the `Ciphers` directive (while it can fall back to the `Cipher`). Quote from the [`ssh` man page](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh):

> `-c cipher_spec`
>
> Selects the cipher specification for encrypting the session.
>   Protocol version 1 allows specification of a single cipher. The supported values are “3des”, “blowfish”, and “des”. For protocol
>   version 2, `cipher_spec` is a comma-separated list of ciphers listed in
>   order of preference. See the `Ciphers` keyword in [ssh_config(5)](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config) for more
>   information.